# Memcache PHP issue: 2 different values for same key

Tags: php, memcached

I have one issue with memcache.

memcache is set on 2 servers. from code, on several places, variable_1 can be set.

problem is that sometime it set on server1 variable_1 = x, and on server2 =>  variable_1 = y. it is set from different part of code, using same function, which map servers good (same list of servers)

thanx

Comment: Are your memcached instances associated with each other? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364564/multiple-servers-and-memcached